# jquery XML feed reader that passes in username/password

Tags: jquery, xml, feed

I'm looking for a jQuery solution that will allow me to read an XML feed that requires authentication.

I have something that partially works, but I don't know how to pass credentials when calling the XML feed.

I know that ideally I shouldn't put credentials in jQuery but they are innocuous in this instance so it's ok.

Comment: Can you specify what type of authentication is used? Is is standard HTTP-AUTH, app-specific etc.??